# Align \Leftrightarrow and "=" (equality) symbols

Tags: align, split

I'm trying to align the \Leftrightarrows, and the equal sign (=), so that the equal signs are all in one row and the \leftrightarrows are in one row.
Thank you in advance for your help.

```
\begin{align}
          \begin{split}
            g ( t + \Delta t ) &= g ( t ) + \Delta t g ' ( t ) + \frac{1}{2} \Delta t^2 g'' ( \tau ), \quad \tau \in ( t, t + \Delta t ).\\
            \overset{\footnotemark}{\Leftrightarrow} g \underbrace{ ( t + \Delta t ) }_{\eqqcolon  \ \tilde{t}} - g(t) &= \Delta tg' ( t ) + \mathcal{O} ( \Delta t^2 ) \quad \text{für}\quad \Delta t \Rightarrow 0\\
            \Leftrightarrow \qquad g (\tilde{t}) - g (t) &= \Delta tg' (t) + \mathcal{O} ( ( \tilde{t} - t ) ^2 ) \quad \text{für}\quad \tilde{t} \rightarrow t.\\
            \Leftrightarrow \qquad g (\tilde{t}) - g (t) \, &\doteq \, \Delta tg' (t).
          \end{split}
        \end{align}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure how the first line should be aligned with respect to the rest, nor I know where exactly you want the equation number. Here is a possible realization. I fixed numerous debatable spacing choices.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather}
g(t+\Delta t) = g(t) + \Delta t  \,g'(t) + \frac{1}{2} \, \Delta t^2 g''( \tau ), \quad \tau \in ( t, t + \Delta t ) \nonumber \\
\begin{aligned}
&\overset{\footnotemark}{\Leftrightarrow} %<-- ??
& g {\underbrace{(t+\Delta t)}_{\eqqcolon\tilde{t}}} - g(t) &= \Delta t \, g'(t) + \mathcal{O}(\Delta t^2) &&\text{für $\Delta t\to0$}\\
&\Leftrightarrow & g(\tilde{t}) - g (t) &= \Delta t \, g'(t) + \mathcal{O}\bigl((\tilde{t}-t)^2\bigr) &&\text{für $\tilde{t} \to t$}\\
&\Leftrightarrow & g(\tilde{t}) - g (t) &\doteq \Delta t \, g' (t).
\end{aligned}
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! This helped me a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Use `alignedat`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{alignedat}{3}
&\quad&
g(t+\Delta t)
&= g(t) + \Delta t g'(t) + \frac{1}{2} \Delta t^2 g''(\tau),
  &\qquad& \tau \in (t,t+\Delta t) 
\\
\overset{\footnotemark}{\Leftrightarrow} &&
g(\,{\underbrace{t+\Delta t}_{\eqqcolon\tilde{t}}}\,) - g(t)
&= \Delta tg'(t) + \mathcal{O}(\Delta t^2)
  && \text{für $\Delta t \Rightarrow 0$}
\\
\Leftrightarrow &&
g(\tilde{t}) - g (t)
&= \Delta tg'(t) + \mathcal{O}((\tilde{t}-t)^2)
  && \text{für $\tilde{t} \rightarrow t$}
\\
\Leftrightarrow &&
g(\tilde{t}) - g (t) 
&\doteq \Delta tg' (t) 
\end{alignedat}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

I made some adjustments: for instance, `\underbrace` should not span the parentheses; it's always a good idea to brace the code for `\underbrace`:

```
{\underbrace{something}_{tag}}
```

because `\underbrace` might affect spacing. I also removed the punctuation, which was inconsistent; reinsert it if you want.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Almost the same solution, and another one with the `ArrowBetweenLines` command from `mathtools`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
      \begin{alignedat}{2}
         & & g ( t + \Delta t ) &= g ( t ) + \Delta t g ' ( t ) + \frac{1}{2} \Delta t^2 g'' ( \tau ), \quad \tau \in ( t, t + \Delta t ).\\
         & \overset{\footnotemark}{\Leftrightarrow} &\qquad g \underbrace{ ( t + \Delta t ) }_{\eqqcolon \ \tilde{t}} - g(t) &= \Delta tg' ( t ) + \mathcal{O} ( \Delta t^2 ) \quad \text{für}\quad \Delta t \Rightarrow 0\\
         & \Leftrightarrow & g (\tilde{t}) - g (t) &= \Delta tg' (t) + \mathcal{O} ( ( \tilde{t} - t ) ^2 ) \quad \text{für}\quad \tilde{t} \rightarrow t.\\
        & \Leftrightarrow & g (\tilde{t}) - g (t) \, &\doteq \, \Delta tg' (t).
      \end{alignedat}
    \end{align}

 \begin{equation}
      \begin{alignedat}{2}
         & & g ( t + \Delta t ) &= g ( t ) + \Delta t g ' ( t ) + \frac{1}{2} \Delta t^2 g'' ( \tau ), \quad \tau \in ( t, t + \Delta t ).\\
          \ArrowBetweenLines
          & \qquad & g \underbrace{ ( t + \Delta t ) }_{\eqqcolon \ \tilde{t}} - g(t) &= \Delta tg' ( t ) + \mathcal{O} ( \Delta t^2 ) \quad \text{für}\quad \Delta t \Rightarrow 0\\
         \ArrowBetweenLines
         & & g (\tilde{t}) - g (t) &= \Delta tg' (t) + \mathcal{O} ( ( \tilde{t} - t ) ^2 ) \quad \text{für}\quad \tilde{t} \rightarrow t.\\
         \ArrowBetweenLines
         & & g (\tilde{t}) - g (t) \, &\doteq \, \Delta tg' (t).
      \end{alignedat}
    \end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!